# How to reinitialize socket after few hours in android?

Tags: android, sockets

The application is not receiving any messages from the server even if it is connected to a server after several ideal hours. How to reconnect them to a server?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that your socket keeps the connection? you should use a timed task to check the connection status periodically.

Comment: Yes. socket keeps connection. I debugged the application and getting `socket.isClosed()` false. But not receiving messages from server.

Comment: is the server working correctly without closing connections?

Comment: yes, server is working properly. I checked with server as well.